Neither `try_compile` nor `try_run` behaves correctly on incorrect source code?
I have this simple C code which checks for MUSL, and otherwise gives syntax which will fail to compile:
set(is_musl_src [=[
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifndef _GNU_SOURCE
    #define _GNU_SOURCE
    #include <features.h>
    #ifndef __USE_GNU
        #define __MUSL__
    #endif
#else
    #include <features.h>
    #ifndef __USE_GNU
        #define __MUSL__
    #endif
#endif

#ifdef __MUSL__
int main(void) {
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
#else
#include "noottt.h"
$$#@ 4 5%905i035 35 45 34%^5
#endif
}
]=])

I've also tried normal syntax at the end there like:
int main(void) {
#ifdef __MUSL__
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
#else
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
#endif
}

However no matter what I try the variables all give the same results on Ubuntu (glibc) and Alpine (musl):
check_c_source_runs("${is_musl_src}" IS_MUSL)
try_compile(COMPILE_RESULT_VAR0
        SOURCE_FROM_VAR is_musl.c is_musl_src
        C_STANDARD 90
)
try_run(RESULT_VAR
        COMPILE_RESULT_VAR1
        SOURCE_FROM_VAR is_musl.c "${is_musl_src}"
        C_STANDARD 90
)
try_run(RESULT_VAR
        COMPILE_RESULT_VAR2
        SOURCE_FROM_VAR is_musl.c is_musl_src
        C_STANDARD 90
)
message(STATUS "IS_MUSL = ${IS_MUSL}")
message(STATUS "RESULT_VAR = ${RESULT_VAR}")
message(STATUS "COMPILE_RESULT_VAR0 = ${COMPILE_RESULT_VAR0}")
message(STATUS "COMPILE_RESULT_VAR1 = ${COMPILE_RESULT_VAR1}")
message(STATUS "COMPILE_RESULT_VAR2 = ${COMPILE_RESULT_VAR2}")


fwiw #error is an easier way to provoke a preprocessor error.

@nneonneo Ok but even with that it continues to says IS_MUSL = 1 ; COMPILE_RESULT_VAR0 = TRUE ; COMPILE_RESULT_VAR1 = FALSE on both Ubuntu and Alpine.

Have you cleared the cache before trying new content of the file? Otherwise, the result of try_compile is cached, so compiling is not performed the next time.

Yes the cache is cleared on each linux distribution

Your mistake is simple, but easy to trip over. Quoting from man 7 feature_test_macros on my local glibc system

NOTE:  In  order to be effective, a feature test macro must be defined before including any header files.

_GNU_SOURCE being one of those feature test macros, must be defined before including any header files. Delete the #include <stdlib.h> from your test.
